# Can I secure a Mac's ad hoc network better than just the default WEP?

Tags: security, ad-hoc

I have created an Ad Hoc network broadcasting from my iMac. Since I am on a University Campus I think it is likely that at least a few people know how to crack WEP. **Is there any way on Mac to use WPA?** I know it is possible with Windows.

Comment: Although there's no easy way to do what you ask, a little more detail on what you are networking might allow us to rovide you with a solution.

Comment: I run my mac as the wireless access point. I have a linux laptop, a chromebook, my ipod and my phone which connect to the wireless. I have currently set it up using wep but feel it is insecure.

Comment: You're right - cracking WEP is a script kiddie type thing these days. Why not set up a VPN on the Mac and have that encrypt things?

Answer (score 4):

I agree the hardware should handle it.

Apple says:  http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.6/en/8339.html

Apple really just wants you to buy an AirPort Extreme or Express.

Comment: Hmm yes I have read that page, but this is surely a software limitation, is there no way around it? I am definitely not buying an AirPort, though might buy a cheap wireless router. Worried about using WEP as I know how easy it is to crack, and there are a fair few other Computer Science students in the building!

Thanks anyway though for your reply.