# How to share internet with WPA/WPA2 security?

Tags: macos, wifi

I'm using a macmini with Mac OS X Snow Leopard to share a cable internet connection. Sharing works fine except that security is limited to 40/128 bit WEP that is insecure (can be hacked in minutes). Is it possible to share the connection via wifi with stronger WPA/WPA2 security? Maybe using some third-party internet sharing app?

Comment: Use an AirPort Express instead of a Mac Mini to share the connection. The Mac internet sharing is seemingly designed for temporary *ad hoc* use.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I secure a Mac's ad hoc network better than just the default WEP?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/42522/can-i-secure-a-macs-ad-hoc-network-better-than-just-the-default-wep)

Comment: The answer you marked is applicable to Mountain Lion, but your question says you're using Snow Leopard.  Consider revising the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mac OS X Mountain Lion supports Internet Sharing using WPA/WPA2.  You will need to upgrade to get this functionality.  [This article has a little more info](http://mac-security.blogspot.com/2012/07/wpa2-encryption-internet-sharing.html).  And here is a screenshot of the new option for WPA2 in Mountain Lion (10.8):

[image: New WPA2 option for Internet Sharing in Mac OS X Mountain Lion]

Comment: Do I have to do something special to get this option? I'm on MacOS X 10.8.1, but I'm just offered "None", "40-bit WEP", and "128-bit WEP"...

Comment: Never mind. I tried to create a WIFI, but I had to enable internet sharing. I thought it would be the same... ;-)

Answer (score 6):

This is not supported in Mac OS X 10.7 and lower. See:

1. [Can I secure a Mac's ad hoc network better than just the default WEP?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/42522/can-i-secure-a-macs-ad-hoc-network-better-than-just-the-default-wep)
2. http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.6/en/8339.html

Perhaps in the next version of the OS, but currently Lion does not accommodate changing the encryption/authentication protocol of an ad-hoc network based from the device.

Though I have looked, there is no software to my knowledge that supports this feature aside from using a separate OS.  You can dual boot: Some versions of [Windows do support this feature](http://sourcedaddy.com/windows-7/creating-an-ad-hoc-wireless-network.html).

Answer (score 3):

It seems that a work-around is to boot into an older version of the OS, configure WPA2, and then boot back.

I set up Internet Sharing a few OS versions ago, and the “Airport Setup” screen had a “Security” dropdown to choose between WEP, WPA, WPA2, and WPA2 Enterprise. Now, running 10.6.8, the “Security” dropdown is gone, and WEP seems to be the only choice. Yet, when I enable sharing on the machine, it still uses the previously-configured WPA2.

Comment: So this setting is saved somewhere. Maybe it's a way to modify it without access to previous OS version?

Comment: If @Randy or another Mac expert can locate the configuration file responsible (probably a .plist somewhere) I am sure a way can be found.