# Is it possible to share an Ethernet connection to a secure wireless network in OS X on a MacBook Pro?

Tags: macos, network, wifi

I can share my Ethernet Internet connection to WiFi clients using System Preferences, but I'm wondering if/how I can make that network secure (WPA) and not broadcast the network name?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Search bar
System Preferences -> Sharing ->  Internet Sharing - Share your connection from ethernet -> to computers using Wifi -> Wifi Options -> Security WEP 128 Bit

This thread is the same as
[How to share internet with WPA/WPA2 security?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/48300/how-to-share-internet-with-wpa-wpa2-security)